# Efficient Javascript Combinations function that doesn't crash browser

Tags: javascript, optimization, combinations, performance, memory-efficient

I have a program that involves the following function for calculating all the possible combinations of a given array:

```
function combinations(arr, k) {
var i,
subI,
sub,
combinationsArray = [],
next;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (k === 1) {
        combinationsArray.push([arr[i]]);
    } else {
        sub = combinations(arr.slice(i + 1, arr.length), k - 1);
        for (subI = 0; subI < sub.length; subI++) {
            next = sub[subI];
            next.unshift(arr[i]);
            combinationsArray.push(next);
        }
    }
}
return combinationsArray;
};
```

For example:

```
 combinations([1,2,3],2);
```

returns:

```
[[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]
```

I use this a lot in my program particularly with an array parameter of 12 objects, to return all the possible combinations of two, from that array. There are 66 possible combinations. In my program, I need to check property values of the object elements of the array returned by this function a lot, to compare them, run conditionals on them etc. 
But the browser crashes when I call functions that use the combinations function like this
(firefox returns the messege: "A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.") It is always a part of the above combinations function thats being called that it crashes on.

I found this : http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/13/speed-up-your-javascript-part-1/
It's meant to be a good method of improving the efficiency of code that calls a function repeatedly (such as in the combinations function).

How could I integrate the combinations function with the method from ncsonline effectively to stop my browser crashing?

Comment: I think to use the setTimeout method, you'd have to apply it not to the combinations function itself, but to whatever loop is calling the combinations function. Producing 66 combinations once should not be that intensive. But web workers might be the way to go for any browser that supports them.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good candidate for using [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers), which run your code on a separate thread.

This way, you won't lock the UI thread (which is what you're seeing now) with intensive computation.

Answer (score 0):

Why build array at all? Can you just iterate through all combinations and do the work inside loop. This should speed-up your logic considerably and make you fit into browser-imposed limits.